# How have Enter as leader?

Tags: vi, vim

I would like to have Enter as my leader in Vim.

When I set

`let mapleader = '<Enter>'` or `let mapleader = '<CR>'`, both options didn't worked for me.

For example, `let mapleader = '/<Space>'` just worked. On the web, I couldn't find nothing.

When I do Ctrl-V in command line, to see my Enter, I get ^M. When I do  as my leader, it didn't worked either.

How could I configure Enter as my leader in Vim?

Thanks in advance for your reply.

Comment: Does `let mapleader = "\<cr>" work? You can always do `nmap <cr> <leader>` if all else fails. However I must say using `<cr>` is great in macros to go the the start of the next line.

Comment: Well, it worked. I sweared I tried "\<Enter>" which is not working. That's oddly, because Vim recognize <Enter>. Thanks for your reply!

Comment: @PeterRincker is there a difference between `<cr>` and `j` in normal mode for macros? I'm thinking to use enter for leader as well.

Comment: @grego `<cr>` goes to _start_ of the next line. `j` simply just moves down. `<cr>` can be useful when recording because you often want to end at the start of the next area. See `:h <CR>`

Answer (score 1):

For any odd leader character, you can use `nr2char()`

```
:let mapleader=nr2char(13)
:nnoremap <leader>x :put='Do something fancy here'<cr>
```

which will use `<enter>` as the `mapleader`.

Answer (score 0):

See comment of Peter Ricker.

The solution is `let mapleader = "\<cr>"` :-)

Happy Vimming!